# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule for Home page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have used this code for make home page multi language site.
my aim is English version run http://example.com and France version run http://example.com/fr

my home page is front page assign.

so I have added bellow code but 404 page show when run http://example.com/fr
I have updated permalink after added this rules. but not working.

so please help me what is solution?

my aim is English version run http://example.com and France version run http://example.com/fr

```
function products_plugin_rules() {
add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)/home', 'index.php?pagename=home&lang=$matches[1]', 'top');    
}
add_action('init', 'products_plugin_rules',10,0);
```

Comment: You are requesting the URL path `/fr` only, so how could the pattern `([^/]*)/home` possibly match ...? There is no `/home` in the path you requested.

Comment: @CBroe I have already try this but not working`function products_plugin_rules() {
add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)', 'index.php?pagename=home&lang=$matches[1]', 'top');    
}
add_action('init', 'products_plugin_rules',10,0);`